# angualar js get total checkbox value

Tags: angularjs

i need to get total checkbox values. this is my sample

```
<ul class="vehicle-menu" ng-show="ques1.enType == 'Not more than 1800 CC – Fuel or Hybrid (Petrol / Diesel)' || ques1.enType == 'Not more than 200 KW electrical vehicles' ">
                      <li><label> <input type="checkbox" ng-change="notTotal()" ng-true-value="20000"  ng-false-value="0" class="checkbox-ex" ng-model="ques1.not1"/> <span>Vehicle 20000.00 </span></label> </li>
                      <li><label>  <input type="checkbox" ng-change="notTotal()" ng-true-value="10000" ng-false-value="0" class="checkbox-ex" ng-model="ques1.not2"/> Driver 10000.00 </label></li>
                      <li><label><input type="checkbox" ng-change="notTotal()" ng-true-value="10000"  ng-false-value="0" class="checkbox-ex" ng-model="ques1.not3"/> Fuel 10000.00 </label></li> 
                      </ul>
```

this is my function

```
    $scope.notTotal = function (){
var notTotalValues = parseInt($scope.ques1.not1) + parseInt($scope.ques1.not2) + parseInt($scope.ques1.not3);
$scope.total = notTotalValues;
}
```

i need to do this work using only function

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (of course it can be implemented with a more dynamic way)

```
$scope.notTotal = function (){
    let totalAmount = 0;

    if($scope.ques1.not1){
        totalAmount += $scope.ques1.not1;
    }
    if($scope.ques1.not2){
        totalAmount += $scope.ques1.not2;
    }
    if($scope.ques1.not3){
        totalAmount += $scope.ques1.not3;
    }

    $scope.total = totalAmount;

}
```

Check a working demo: [DEMO](https://codepen.io/papadon1/pen/xxbzEbY)